# Docker- .sh file not found in path

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, dockerfile

In my new **Symfony** application, I am trying to run `docker-compose build` when I get an error:

In my root bin folder I have the file from the error message. I am starting to question if this is a path problem? Can someone please help? Maybe it is something wrong with ***volume*** definition in the docker file I posted below.

> ```
> RUN /var/www/html/bin/app_build.sh:
> #19 0.164 /bin/sh: 1: /var/www/html/bin/app_build.sh: not found
> ```

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    app-www:
        container_name: app-www
        hostname: app-www
        restart: unless-stopped
        entrypoint: apache2-foreground
        build:
            context: .
            args:
                ENVIRONMENT: local
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html
            - ./.docker/.ssh:/root/.ssh
            - ./www/node_modules:/var/www/html/node_modules:rw,cached
            - ./www/vendor:/var/www/html/vendor:rw,cached
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
            - "8081:443"
        depends_on:
            - redis
    redis:
        image: redis:6.2-alpine
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '6363:6379'
        command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning
        volumes:
            - cache:/data
volumes:
    cache:
        driver: local
```

and `dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
ENV TZ="Europe/Zurich"
ARG COMPOSER_TOKEN
ENV COMPOSER_TOKEN=${COMPOSER_TOKEN}

# Debian Packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get --yes --no-install-recommends install libxml2-dev libgmp-dev zip npm zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libonig-dev git unzip tzdata \
    && npm install --global yarn

# PHP Extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap bcmath gmp pdo pdo_mysql intl opcache gd json mbstring gmp \
    && docker-php-ext-enable soap bcmath gmp pdo pdo_mysql intl opcache gd json mbstring gmp \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis

# Install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN mkdir /root/.composer && echo "${COMPOSER_TOKEN}" > /root/.composer/auth.json

# Configure PHP
COPY ./config/docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# Configure Apache
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/* /etc/apache2/sites-available/
COPY ./config/docker/apache2/breitling.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
COPY ./config/docker/apache2/ssl/ /etc/apache2/ssl/

# Deploy & Build app
COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN /var/www/html/bin/app_build.sh

# Fix permissions
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var/

EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT /var/www/html/bin/entrypoint.sh
```

I am not sure what is wrong as this is the main config for my project. And I am running it on MacOs.

Comment: The Dockerfile build step doesn't see `volumes:` at all, and in fact the `volumes:` will hide the results of the image build.  What's in your Dockerfile?  Do you need to `COPY` code into the image, instead of mounting it with `volumes:`?

Comment: As it is a script, could it be a permission issue? Does this file exist inside the container and has execution permission?

Comment: In mu dockerfile: COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN /var/www/html/bin/app_build.sh @DavidMaze

Comment: What is the very very first line of the script?  Is it executable?  Are you working on a Windows host system, and if so, is it possible the script has DOS line endings?

Comment: In order to debug this kind of questions, you can "enter" the image with `docker exec -it $IMAGE_ID bash` and directly check its internals. You get the image ID from the build process, just take the ID of the last layer that built successfully. You probably need to locate the shell file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the image was never created as it failed due to an error I have posted. @Green绿色

Comment: But the previous layer was created. Each layer is its own image. So, you can enter the previous layer instead and check it out.

Comment: `Step X/Y : COPY  . /var/www/html/  ---> Running in a16d2a2456b3 Removing intermediate container a16d2a2456b3 ---> ecd99e709d0a` -> from this take the last hash number as input to `docker exec -it`

Comment: Just to debug your problem, you could insert `RUN pwd && ls` just before `COPY . /var/www/html/` so when you build you should see if in `.` there is what you what to copy.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into these lines:

```
COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN /var/www/html/bin/app_build.sh
```

I would expect that inside path `/var/www/html/` there is again `www` directory.

My guess is that you need only the contents of the www dir copied into the docker image. Then your copy command should look like this:

```
COPY ./www/ /var/www/html/
```

Give it a shot :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I replaced this COPY line with your suggestion and i got:  > [stage-0 13/15] COPY ./www/ /var/www/html/:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/www" not found: not found
@michail_w Did I do something wrong? :)

Comment: Do I need to create www folder in the project rood dir to make it work?